# wordpress URL with Apache and Domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, url

I'm using the latest wordpress version, I installed it on another machine in my network on Apache and PHP5.

Then I bought a domain, I noted that the wordpress points to css and images on the local server (for ex: http://192.168.1.33/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css) so the visitor who use my domain cannot show my website normally.

Then I changed the address from the control panel in wordpress to my domain, but I can't enter it again because I can't see my domain like any others because I'm in the same network so the domain returned the router homepage!

I don't know PHP, so I opened mysql and modified `site_url` and `home` from `wp_options` table, I changed their values to "/" to be relative URL, but it caused some problems in the css and js files for `login.php`, and css files for top admin bar.

My domain is: http://www.darelnadwa.com/

if I put "www.darelnadwa.com" in the wordpress administrator settings, I'll see the blog as a plain HTML without CSS and Images, but the visitor will see it normally.

If I put "192.168.1.33" in the wordpress administrator settings, I'll see the blog normally with CSS and Images, but the visitor will see it as a plain HTML.

I can't visit www.darelnadwa.com unless I used a proxy, so I'm using the machine IP in my network.

How can I solve this problem without using proxy for surfing my website on my network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and revert all your changes and add these lines at the top of your `wp-config.php` file

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.darelnadwa.com'); //no trailing slash for both
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.darelnadwa.com');
```

Comment: Okay, Now I can't browse the blog from my network, I can't use http://192.168.1.33/ and have to use www.darelnadwa.com that I can't open in my network because it returned the router page! Now I have to use proxy to visit my website.

Comment: are you serving the blog from your own machine? The blog I'm seeing on www.darelnadwa.com  is not the same as I saw earlier, so has you chang worked? If you can't access it, it might be a router issues rather than anything with wordpress

Comment: Yes, I serving the blog on another machine in the same network. 
No, I changed the theme now, and changed the path to "www.darelnadwa.com" so you can see it normally, but I can't visit it from the Internal network. I've to use proxy to visit it, or it will returned the router page.
It's a problem from wordpress because it depends on the real path, but it should depends on relative path like: "/style.css". I've a phpBB forum and it's working very good either in the Internal network or from Outside.

Comment: If I visit it from http://192.168.1.33 it will try to download styles and images from www.darelnadwa.com so I can't show the blog normally like you, I've to use proxy!

Comment: No, I meant, that is dependent on the theme (whether you use relative or real path). You might try adding `www.darelnadwa.com` to your hosts file so that you can access it from there. -might- help

Comment: I added this line `192.168.1.33   darelnadwa.com` to /etc/hosts in the Server Machine. but no effect. It's not dependent on the theme, it depends on the wordpress administrator settings that I've to put the real domain there.

Comment: But if you put it in hosts, and make your real url your domain, then when you access it locally you'll be served from your local network rather than over the internet right? so that should solve your problem

Comment: if I put "www.darelnadwa.com" in the wordpress administrator settings, I'll see the blog as a plain HTML without CSS and Images, but the visitor will see it normally.

if I put "192.168.1.33" in the wordpress administrator settings, I'll see the blog normally with CSS and Images, but the visitor will see it as a plain HTML.

I can't visit www.darelnadwa.com unless I used a proxy, so I'm using the machine IP in my network.

Comment: How can I add it to /etc/hosts/, I added this line: `192.168.1.33 darelnadwa.com`, is this line right?

Comment: Yeah, that line is right. Sorry, I don't know much about network configurations. That should work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked very good. I've to put this line in the /etc/hosts of the server and the /etc/hosts of my laptop so I can surf my blog like you surf it!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line
`192.168.1.33 www.darelnadwa.com`
to your `/etc/hosts` file (for *nix and Mac OS X) or `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` (for Windows XP, 7, 8).